# How to solve formula in natural deduction

Tags: logic, proof, proof-of-correctness

I need your help. I need to proof this formula but I dont know how. I tried close everything what came to my mind, but I cant finish all branches. Here is my bad try. [My bad try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5OGA.png)

FORMULA: ((K ∧ A) ⇒ (U ∨ B)) ∨ ((K ∧ A) ∧ (¬U ∧ ¬B))
I will be really grateful for all your help.. Ty